# What is the time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

```
public static void Comp(int n)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            for(int k=1;k<n;k*=2)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Does anyone knows what the time complexity is?

And what is the Big Oh()

Please can u explain this to me, step by step?

Comment: I think it's N^2 * logN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever gave you this problem is almost certainly looking for the answer `n^2 log(n)`, for reasons explained by others.

However the question doesn't really make any sense. If `n > 2^30`, `k` will overflow, making the inner loop infinite.

Even if we treat this problem as being completely theoretical, and assume `n`, `k` and `count` aren't Java `int`s, but some theoretical integer type, the answer `n^2 log n` assumes that the operations `++` and `*=` have constant time complexity, no matter how many bits are needed to represent the integers. This assumption isn't really valid.

### Update

It has been pointed out to me in the comments below that, based on the way the hardware works, it *is* reasonable to assume that `++`, `*=2` and `<` all have constant time complexity, no matter how many bits are required. This invalidates the third paragraph of my answer.

Comment: That's usually the assumption, which is not incorrect. Multiplication by 2 is just a shift operation in hardwhare and `++` is just a counter, which is a constant clock cycle. check out http://teahlab.com/ especially the counter articles/circuits. So the question is not as theoretical as you might think. In hardware the assumptions are correct.

Comment: accepting this as the answer shows just how lost and confused the OP is. The question is not as theoretical as this guy assumes, and he just mentions that the other answers are correct. So how is this the correct answer? A little thinking, friend. A little thinking.

Comment: @KonsolLabapen for the shift operation (i.e. multiply by 2), would the Parallel access shift register work? http://teahlab.com/4-Bit_Parallel_Access_Shift_Register/ I went to the site and search for the word `shift` and that's what came up.

Comment: You would need a much bigger one than 4-bit, but yea. It should work for shifting and any large counter for counting.

Comment: @KatedralPillon I was very surprised when this answer was accepted, but technically it is the only correct one here. The inner loop *does* becomes infinite if `n > 2^30`, making any talk of the asymptotic behaviour meaningless. As for the hardware argument, I don't know enough about it, but is `<` really `O(1)` independent of the number of bits involved? In any case, my basic point (that the fact that `++`, `*=2` and `<` are constant time operations is an *assumption*) is correct.

Comment: I am not a hardware expert but the overflow argument does not make any sense unless you are making unwarranted assumptions about the hardware. Why is `n>2^30` considered infinite? Why do we assume k will overflow? Who said anything about this being a window's PC computer? I did basic hardware in college and I can see from the linked articles that indeed the number of bits is insignificant in this problem.

Comment: @KonsolLabapen What about `<`? Is that `O(1)`?

Comment: This is certainly an interesting discussion. If you look at the way gates work (by gates I mean integrated circuits): gates are not aware of each other. There is no cascading propagation in a shift register. Each gate looks at its input. And when the clock cycle comes in, at that instant each gate computes based on its input signal. So you can have a billion gates. If they are arranged in parallel, they will all compute simultaneously on the clock. So yes `O(1)` is actually correct. And these shift registers can be purchased at your local hardware store, so nothing special really.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is `O(n^2 log n)`. Why? each for-loop is a function of `n`. And you have to multiply by n for each for loop; except the inner loop which grows as log n. why? for each iteration k is multiplied by 2. Think of merge sort or binary search trees.

**details**

for the first two loops: summation of 1 from 0 to n, which is n+1 and so the first two loops give `(n+1)*(n+1)= n^2+2n+1= O(n^2)`

for the k loop, we have k growing as 1,2,4,8,16,32,... so that 2^k = n. Take the log of both sides and you get `k=log n`

Again, not clear?

[image]

So if we set `m=0`, and `a=2` then we get `-2^n/-1` why is a=2? because that is the a value for which the series yields 2,4,8,16,...2^k

Comment: Incorrect, the most inner for loop takes log(n), making the final product O(n^2 log(n))

Comment: He probably wants the tightest bound one can give, which this one isn't.

Comment: @G.Bach I hardly believe that the most inner loop is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

In theory this is `O(n^2 * log(n))`.

Each of two outer loops is `O(n)` and the inner one is `O(log(n))`, because `log base 2` of `n` is the number of times which you have to divide `n` by `2` to get `1`.

Also this is a strict bound, i.e the code is also `Θ(n^2 * log(n))`